# Wolfram Language symbols by their Ranks

Tags: performance-tuning, curated-data, core-language, sorting, entity

I'd like to get the top 50, the bottom 50 and an ordered list of all Wolfram Language symbols based on their `"Ranks"`.
With

```
allWLS = EntityList["WolframLanguageSymbol"];
```

this returns the top 50

```
Pick[allWLS, 
 UnitStep[Replace[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks"], 
     m_Missing -> {{Infinity, Infinity}}, {1}][[All, 1, 2]] - 51], 0]
```

this should return the bottom 50

```
maxRank = Max[Replace[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks"], 
 m_Missing -> {{0, 0}}, {1}][[All, 1, 2]]]

Pick[allWLS, 
 UnitStep[Replace[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks"], 
     m_Missing -> {{0, 0}}, {1}][[All, 1, 2]] - (maxRank - 51)], 1]
```

but returns the bottom 38 (all having an `"All"` rank of 4469), and

```
orderedWLS = 
  allWLS[[Ordering[
     Replace[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks"], 
       m_Missing -> {{Infinity, Infinity}}, {1}][[All, 1, 2]]]]];
```

returns a list of all Wolfram Language symbols ordered by their `"All"` rank.
The bottom 50 can then be found with

```
orderedWLS[[-50 - # ;; -# - 1]] &@
 Count[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks"], _Missing]
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to get this done faster within the [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) framework? Especially using `Replace` feels kind of odd here. There should be a way to get for example the top 50 by using `Interval[{1, 50}]` directly for the `Entity`s, similar to the following example for `"VersionIntroduced"`:

   ```
   WolframLanguageData[
    EntityClass[
     "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"VersionIntroduced" -> Interval[{10.2, 10.3}]}]]
   ```
2. Is there a way to do this faster by circumventing the use of `Entity`s completely or partially (e.g. by preprocessing the downloaded data)?

Comment: The problem is that `WolframLanguageData[]` itself uses `Entity[]` to return results, and the ranks seem to only be accessible through Alpha or the corresponding `EntityValue[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I was thinking of using something like `WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"VersionIntroduced" -> 
    Interval[{10.2, 10.3}]}]]`, but couldn't make it work for `"Ranks"`.

Comment: @J.M. To me the real problem (with respect to 1.) seems to be that `"Ranks"` are lists and not single values.

Comment: I think that's because the ranks aren't for one field, but for several; e.g. `WolframLanguageData["Sin", "Ranks"]`. My comment was more intended to address point 2; that is; I don't see any obvious way to avoid going online just to get the function ranks.

Comment: @J.M. An example where multiple fields are no problem `WolframLanguageData["Plot", "FunctionalityAreas"]`, `WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", 
   "PlottingFunctions"}]]`.

Comment: @Karsten @J.M. I was able to copy, paste and execute the code. Could you enlighten me as to what the ranks of the ***WolframLanguageSymbol*** represent? A complete guess on my part is how many hits they are getting on various web sites? This is my first exposure to `Entity`, one of the things I like about Stack Exchange is to broaden my horizons.

Comment: @Jack, I interpreted them as how "popular" a function is as used in a particular field/domain. For instance, if you execute `WolframLanguageData["Sin", "Ranks"]`, you'll see that one of the entries is StackExchange.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for the reply. That seems reasonable, the number one rank symbol is `List` and the number two `Rule` using **All** as the rank.

Comment: @JackLaVigne `EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks", "Description"]` returns `"ranks of usage"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This gives 5 symbols with the highest rank in "All":

```
In[1]:= EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks", 
  "EntityAssociation"] // Query[TakeSmallest[5] /* Keys, "All"]

Out[1]= {Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "List"], 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Rule"], 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Times"], 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Power"], 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Plus"]}
```

It is currently not possible to get the same result without retrieving all the data because a query like

```
EntityList[EntityClass[type, "property" -> value]]
```

is executed only when `value` is a simple expression like a number, quantity, entity, ..., or one of a selection of operators like `ContainsAny[{entity1, ...}]`, `GreaterThan[x]`, ... .

Answer (score 5):

The `"Corpus"` qualifier can be used to generate an efficient query.

```
EntityList[
 EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks", {"Corpus" -> "All"}] -> 
   TakeSmallest[50]]]
```

[image: Out]

There are examples for this in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html?#1440500603) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html?#216238974) now.

Comment: It's worth noting that this seems to be part of an update of the Entity framework and not of Mathematica itself. Therefore this also works in version 10 and not only in version 11.

Comment: OTOH, one now wonders if it was already built-in and was just not documented before…

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to convert the result of `EntityValue[]` into a `Dataset[]` and then perform ranking/sorting queries. Here is what I came up with:

```
wlranks = Dataset[Association /@ MapAt["Name" -> # &, Prepend[#2, #1] & @@@
                  DeleteMissing[EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol",
                                            {"Name", "Ranks"}], 1, 1], {All, 1}]]
```

Here's how to query the top 50 functions by their `"All"` ranking:

```
wlranks[TakeSmallestBy[#All &, 50], "Name"] // Normal
   {"List", "Rule", "Times", "Power", "Plus", "Set", "Alternatives", "Null",
    "Blank", "NoWhitespace", "Pattern", "$Failed", "CompoundExpression", "Slot",
    "Part", "Sqrt", "RGBColor", "None", "Pi", "SetDelayed", "Function", "Equal",
    "Subscript", "Automatic", "True", "Directive", "I", "Map", "Opacity",
    "RuleDelayed", "FinancialData", "GrayLevel", "Sin", "False", "If", "Hold",
    "Quantity", "ReplaceAll", "CityData", "Line", "Cos", "Condition", "Less",
    "Style", "And", "E", "Table", "HoldComplete", "Word", "Length"}
```

A problem I noticed with querying the bottom 50 is that there seems to be a lot of ties at the bottom. With that caveat, you can use `TakeLargestBy[]` to extract the bottom 50. A sorted list of the functions ranked by `"All"` is returned by `wlranks[SortBy[#All &], "Name"] // Normal`. Similar operations can be done for the other ranks, e.g. `"StackExchange"`:

```
wdd[TakeSmallestBy[#StackExchange &, 50], "Name"] // Normal
   {"List", "Times", "Set", "Power", "Rule", "Blank", "Pattern", "Slot",
    "CompoundExpression", "Plus", "Part", "Function", "SetDelayed", "Map",
    "Equal", "Null", "Pi", "ReplaceAll", "Table", "Apply", "Sin", "All", "True",
    "Length", "Sqrt", "RuleDelayed", "Range", "Cos", "If", "Derivative", "False",
    "First", "Less", "Flatten", "Greater", "Module", "Plot", "Transpose",
    "PlotRange", "I", "None", "Red", "LessEqual", "And", "ImageSize",
    "StringCases", "With", "Graphics", "PatternTest", "Dynamic"}
```

Comment: What does this mean, the "rank" of a symbol? Just how frequently it appears in a given codebase?

Comment: @Oleksandr, yes, that was my reading of it; taking the last one as an example, `List` is the most popular *Mathematica* function in StackExchange posts, followed by `Times`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Ranks", "Description"]` returns `"ranks of usage"`. One can get the `"frequencies of usage"` by using `"Frequencies"` instead of `"Ranks"`.

Comment: One can avoid making two downloads and save some time by using `EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"Name", "Ranks"}]` instead of `WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], {"Name", "Ranks"}]`.

Comment: @Karsten, I've changed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Karsten7. the problem is that I don't think "ranks of usage" really means anything. If this is what is intended, it would have been far clearer to write "rank order by frequency of usage in a given corpus". "Ranks" can easily be understood as identifying tensor-valued functions such as `D`, or relating to any of the higher-order functions.

Comment: @Oleksandr, they certainly could have picked a less ambiguous name for the field.